# saving a video/audio session created through webrtc peerConnection

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I have created an application where I am able to start a video conference between two clients using **webRTC peerConnection api**.
I have used **node.js** for server side scripting and **socket.io** for socket implementation. Now I want to record this live video chat session and save it.
How to go about it? I tried to find out but haven't got anything. Maybe I am not looking at the right place. Please help.

Comment: I think this will help you http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets simmilarly you can save video also

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly help you on Node.js, but you could use the [C++ API](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis) on a server and record from that. There's a [sample client app](https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/#svn/trunk/talk/examples/peerconnection/client) in the webrtc.org repository.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I will look into that sample, however i was wondering could we convert the mediastreams in some video format like mp4 and then save them

Comment: By using the application above, you should be able to access the compressed audio/video from the other client. However, then you will have to use ffmpeg library to dump those into a mp4 file. I don't think webrtc supports creating an mp4 just yet.